# Looping through in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Hi i have a database of users in a ruby project and i need to loop through each of them and get their values. How do you loop? I know that you can use

```
model.find(i)
```

and get each element but how do you loop till the last element?

Answer (score 6):

I assume you're using rails & active record. If so, do

```
User.all.each do |user|
  # your code here
end
```

or

```
User.find_each do |user|
  # your code here
end
```

The former loads all users from the database at once, the latter -- loads records in batches, which is helpful if you have a lot of records.

In ruby iterators are used a lot and usually the standard module called Enumerable is used for that: [An Introduction to Ruby's Enumerable Module](http://jamesgolick.com/2008/1/5/an-introduction-to-ruby-s-enumerable-module.html)

Answer (score 3):

As Ross said in his answer `array.each` is the best way to loop.

But in the case of ActiveRecord you should take a look at the Rails Guide section on [Loading in Batches](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches).

You could very easily say `User.all.each`, but if you have 1,000,000 users, this may well crash your server.

It's much better to say

```
User.find_each do |user|
  * do something *
end
```

And let Active Record look after your memory behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to loops 
Say you have a users object

you can do

```
users.each do |user|

   puts user.name

end
```

this is easiest way to loop

other ways could be using for loop, while loop other loops in rails 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm